# Vapor db Invalid SQL relation doesn't exist Fluent tries to SELECT from wrong db name

Tags: postgresql, vapor

When I look into my PostreSQL server after preparation I see the relation with the name "blogdetails" but when I try to do

```
try BlogDetails.all()
```

I always get the error "invalidSQL("Error relation \"blogdetailss\" does not exist" spelled this way ending with two Ss which makes no sense to me, Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, I've tried dropdb and createdb over again and reverting and preparing :(
This is from my main.swift

```
try? drop.addProvider(VaporPostgreSQL.Provider.self)
drop.preparations = [BlogComment.self, BlogDetails.self]

do {
    try drop.database?.prepare([BlogComment.self, BlogDetails.self])
    print("Database prepared")
} catch {
     print("Prepare failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

And this is my model

```
struct BlogDetails: Model {

var id: Node?
var exists: Bool = false

let title: String
let author: String
let brief: String
let dateString: String

fileprivate static let entityName = "blogdetails"

init(id: Node? = nil, title: String, author: String, brief: String, dateString: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.brief = brief
    self.dateString = dateString
}

init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    self.id = try node.extract(Keys.id)
    self.title = try node.extract(Keys.title)
    self.author = try node.extract(Keys.author)
    self.brief = try node.extract(Keys.brief)
    self.dateString = try node.extract(Keys.dateString)
}

func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
    return try Node(node: [
        Keys.id: id,
        Keys.title: title,
        Keys.author: author,
        Keys.brief: brief,
        Keys.dateString: dateString
    ])
}
}

extension BlogDetails: Preparation {
    static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create(BlogDetails.entityName) {  in
            .id()
            .string(Keys.title)
            .string(Keys.author)
            .string(Keys.brief)
            .string(Keys.dateString)
        }
    }

    static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.delete(BlogDetails.entityName)
    }
}

extension BlogDetails {
    struct Keys {
        static let id = "id"
        static let title = "title"
        static let author = "author"
        static let brief = "brief"
        static let dateString = "date_string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity name for queries is taken from `static var entity: String { get }`

Override the default value of this in your class.

i.e. instead of

`fileprivate static let entityName = "blogdetails"`

Use

`fileprivate static let entity = "blogdetails"`